# if $a\times b=a\times c$ then $a || b-c$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> Prove: if $a\times b=a\times c$ then $a || b-c$ when $a\neq 0$

So we have $$a\times b=a\times c\iff a\times b-a\times c=0\iff a\times(b-c) =0$$

So
$$0=a\times(b-c)=|a|*|b-c|\sin \theta $$ Therefore
$$ \sin \theta\Rightarrow\theta=0,\pi$$

But what happen if $b=c$ can we still say that $a || b-c$?

Comment: No. If $b = c$, then $b - c = 0$ and we do not have the "parallel" relation you want here. You must mention here that $a$ is parallel to $b - c$ if $b \neq c$.

Comment: Are there vectors $a$ parallel to the zero vector?

Comment: If b=c then how can you check parallel to null vector?

Comment: **Yes**, it is usual to define parallelity (and orthogonality) so that $0$ is parallel (and orthogonal) to all vectors.

Answer (score 1):

That all depends to your definition of parallelity of the **zero vector**. A definition may say that *the zero vector is not parallel to any vector since it actually is a point and the parallelity of a point and a line isn't well defined.*

Another definition is as follows:

*Two vectors are parallel only if they have the same direction, say, their angles are equal with any given line.*

Based on this definition, regardless of the magnitude of the zero vector, since the angle of it **can be any real number** then is parallel to any other vector, yet this definition **has a flaw.** If two vectors are parallel pairwise with a third vector, then the two themselves are also parallel. The latter definition breaks this property. Anyway, you must clarify your definition of parallelity of the zero vector.

Comment: A definition of parallel one can use is $v||w$ if $v=cw$ for some scalar $c$.  This is symmetric EXCEPT if one of the vectors is zero.  Then, $0||w$ for any $w$, but $v||0$ never holds for non-zero $v$.  This captures our notion of parallel outside of this edge case, but illustrates how coming up with good definitions is harder than it might appear, and that finding the right definition isn't always obvious.  If we require ourselves to think carefully about if we want $0$ to be parallel to other vectors, then the answer isn't clear to me.  I accept that we usually do, but we lose transitivity.

Comment: That's right if we also consider the transitivity, symmetry and reflection (which of course should be preserved for an equivalence class like parallelity). I just skewed the definition a bit dropping either one or two of these properties to highlight the difference between notations and definitions and the consequences the may yield to.